# Dynamic data in a custom attribute

Tags: php, jquery, html

I use

```
$('.test').attr('data-payment', 'value');
```

to create a custom attribute for

```
<table class="test" data-payment="value">
```

further down the table I have

```
<td class="outlay">100</td>
```

The table is outputted using a PHP script, it is a sort of calculator that updates when form fields are changed and a button is clicked.

My question is how to insert the contents of `.outlay` into the `data-payment` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$('#button').clicked(function(){
  var val = $('.outlay').text(); // Store content in val variable
  $('.test').attr('data-payment', val); // change data-payment value 
})
```

Comment: Oh I see how it works now. I am learning, obviously :) I have used your code for the solution. Thanks

Comment: @kurts thanks & good luck to you :) do upvote the answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: Thanks. I am unable to upvote yet, but I will when I am able.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using data-attributes, you can use things like:

```
$('.test').data('payment');
```

In your case, you'll want something like:

```
var outlay = $('.outlay').text();
$('.test').data('payment', outlay);
```

Comment: Thanks it does do what I want, though I have used Jigar's code. I would upvote you but can't yet :(